# Mac OSX: What is the best pagination method to load more data for NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pagination, nstableview

I am trying to find a method to allow me to load more data in NSTableView so the user can see all of his data. However, I am only use to iOS development and not Mac OSX development. iOS has a way where you can pull down on the UITableView to load more data. Is there such a method for Mac OSX development or is there a better alternative? I heard something about using "pages" to achieve this, but I don't know if it is the best way. I google this, but keeps giving me iOS results.

P.S. I will appreciate it if your provided visual and code examples so I can better understand.

Edit: I see this piece of code on the internet. I guess I can implement something like this to load few data at a time. Fetch data can grab the next 100 data for each page.

```
@interface ViewController : NSObject {
    NSTableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *mDataSource;
    NSInteger mPageNumber;
    NSInteger mTotalPage;
}
-(IBAction)nextPage : (id)sender;//for next page
-(IBAction)prevPage : (id)sender;// for prev. page
-(void)fetchData;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@end
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        mDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        mPageNumber=0;
        mTotalPage =2;// total numer of pages
        [self fetchData];
    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)nextPage : (id)sender;
{
    ++mPageNumber;
    if (mTotalPage<=mPageNumber) {
        mPageNumber=0;// point to first page
    }
    [self fetchData];

}
-(IBAction)prevPage : (id)sender;
{
    --mPageNumber;
    [self fetchData];
}

-(void)fetchData;
{
    [tableView setDataSource:nil];
    NSString *lDataSourcePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/page%d",mPageNumber];
    NSArray *lDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:lDataSourcePath];
    [mDataSource setArray:lDataSource];
    [lDataSource release];
    [lDataSourcePath release];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [mDataSource release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark Data Source
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [mDataSource count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [mDataSource objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

Comment: visual and code examples -> and u get paid for it ;) nice try

Comment: This is where you should start https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/iSpend/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003625 If the window stretches tableview asks for more data. You can programatically scroll if you need and tableview will ask for more data.

Answer (score 0):

Others have downvoted and voted to close this question because it is (truly) a bit too vague. It also seems like you're asking about two different things: 1) How to paginate your data source so the table only shows a page of data at a time and, 2) How to handle this in the user interface.

In order to answer your pagination question, you'll need to provide a lot more information about the nature of the data, why you feel the need to paginate it, where it's coming from (ie, how does it get into your data source), etc.

In order to answer your UI question, we'll need to know more about what your data represents and how the user is expected to use it, because there are several different approaches.

For example, the "Pulling top-down to refresh" may just reload the data, not append to it (this isn't really for "pagination", just "updated info"). However, this could be used as a way to load the "previous page" worth of data. Pull hard enough and it moves to the previous page (and the users find themselves at the bottom of the previous page). Get to the end and pull hard enough and the next page is loaded (users find themselves at the top of the scroll list of the next page). There are dozens of open source examples out there (search Github) that show you how to do a pull-to-refresh on the Mac. This can be pretty easily adapted to this purpose.

Another example would be to add a "load next/prev x" entry to the top and bottom of your data source, where needed. Obviously the first page wouldn't have the "load previous x" and the last page wouldn't have the "load next x" entries, since you're at the beginning/end. If your "page size" is 100 rows and you have 100+ rows of total data, then your first page would hold 101 total rows (but the last one is a button that says "load 100 more..."). Clicking that last row behaves like the previous example I gave. If you're in the "middle" (you can load 100 prev and 100 next), your table is given 102 rows (first and last are nav controls); if at the end, back to 101, but the nav button is the first row in your table.

Another example might be to eliminate this altogether and have a page control in the toolbar, maybe a segmented control with first/prev/position,next,last buttons like so:  [ |<  <  (101-200)  >  >| ] ... the position segment (that shows the page's range) could be clickable and allow you to specify page size and/or jump directly to a page by typing it in.

The above examples illustrate why your question is far too vague to answer. I encourage you to start a new question for your UI portion (with very specific details about the nature of the data and what your users will do with it, etc.). Start a separate question, if necessary, for how to build a custom data source that allows for data pagination. Again, be very specific about the nature of the data, where it comes from, etc., as I mentioned above. Without this information, you'll only be able to get vague answers (though more specific answers to vague questions means an answerer made some assumptions and may end up confusing you further). So always be specific.

I hope this helps.